# Blender black screen render

Tags: rendering

I made a model of Harry Potter. but when  I render the model it's just a black screen.Duplication is on none. Seams to be nothing wrong with the node setup and render icon is checked on all the objects except the hair which I don't need to render. Thank you for taking the time to read this. Please help.

[link to the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Bijm169jY7zLowt3ri9rsPs3cwSpdhBK)

Comment: I flagged to reopen this question because problem that appeared in scene (Muted Render layer In Node editor) are not represented in duplicate suggestions.

Comment: @Crantisz You can always edit or add to existing questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 mistakes.

1) You Muted Render layer In Node editor.

So go in Node editor, Compositing mode, select Render Layers Node and unmute it using <kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

2) You hide all objects in render. Click on camera icon to make them visible in render:

[image]